# React redux sub application

Tags: reactjs, backbone.js, redux, react-router

I'm wondering if it possible to create a sub application inside my backbone application with react redux? It will have a few pages, just to prove concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course! `react-dom` can attach a React element to any sub-part of your application.

```
reactDOM.render(<MyReactApp/>, $('#some-node').get(0));
```

Comment: What would happen with store after changing route to backbone routes, should I stick to backbone router or should I use react router + react router redux?

Comment: @user6307388 I'd stick with Backbone route if you intend to mix both for a while.

Comment: Thx for your answer!